# Unable to run RSEM tool because of error rsem-parse-alignments : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compiler-errors, compilation

I downloaded the `RSEM` software package for estimating gene and isoform expression levels from RNA-Seq data, then compiled RSEM in the `MacOS X` terminal using `make` in the same directory, throws many errors and warnings:

```
In file included from simulation.cpp:22:
In file included from ./SingleModel.h:16:
In file included from ./Orientation.h:8:
In file included from ./simul.h:6:
In file included from ./boost/random.hpp:52:
In file included from ./boost/random/generate_canonical.hpp:22:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions.hpp:15:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions/airy.hpp:10:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:21:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:25:
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:91:24: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
          boost::math::tuple<T, T> operator()(const T& x) const
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:94:33: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
            return boost::math::make_tuple(
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:142:24: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
          boost::math::tuple<T, T> operator()(const T& x) const
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:145:33: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
            return boost::math::make_tuple(
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from simulation.cpp:22:
In file included from ./SingleModel.h:16:
In file included from ./Orientation.h:8:
In file included from ./simul.h:6:
In file included from ./boost/random.hpp:52:
In file included from ./boost/random/generate_canonical.hpp:22:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions.hpp:15:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions/airy.hpp:10:
In file included from ./boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:21:
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:62:22: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
        boost::math::tuple<T, T> operator()(const T& z) const
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:78:31: error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
          return boost::math::tuple<T, T>(the_function, its_derivative);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:78:37: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
          return boost::math::tuple<T, T>(the_function, its_derivative);
                                    ^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:56:25: note: declared here
      template<typename T>
                        ^
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:211:24: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
          boost::math::tuple<T, T> operator()(const T& x) const
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
6 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [simulation.o] Error 1
```

Then, tried running `RSEM`

```
./rsem-calculate-expression --bowtie2 --bowtie2-path /Users/Documents/Bioinformatics_tools/Bowtie2/bowtie2-2.5.0-macos-x86_64  -p 8  --output-genome-bam --paired-end /Users/Documents/Bioinformatics_tools/SRA/fastq_dir/SRR1039508_1.fastq /Users/Documents/Bioinformatics_tools/SRA/fastq_dir/SRR1039508_2.fastq /Users/Documents/Bioinformatics_tools/Bowtie2/index/GRCh38_noalt_as/GRCh38_noalt_as  hg_paired_end_quals
```

but it shows the below error, I guess this is searching for this file, but this not generated after compiling using `make` command?

> rsem-parse-alignments : No such file or directory!

I tried to trouble shoot the issue using this link but unsuccessful  [rsem-calculate-expression error](https://github.com/deweylab/RSEM/issues/51) and ["make" error on mac](https://github.com/deweylab/RSEM/issues/189)

Best Regards,

Toufiq

Comment: At a glance it seems to have nothing to with programming, but using RSEM/Bowtie2.

Comment: Indeed the other error has nothing to with programing, as [confirmed here](https://github.com/deweylab/RSEM/issues/51#issuecomment-304760000)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the make errors on MAC:

```
./boost/math/tools/tuple.hpp:18:14: error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'std'
./boost/math/tools/tuple.hpp:21:14: error: no member named 'ignore' in namespace 'std'
./boost/math/tools/tuple.hpp:22:14: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'std'
./boost/math/tools/tuple.hpp:23:14: error: no member named 'tie' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'time'?
./boost/math/tools/roots.hpp:202:20: error: no member named 'tie' in namespace 'boost::math'; did you mean 'time'?
./boost/math/tools/roots.hpp:297:20: error: no member named 'tie' in namespace 'boost::math'; did you mean 'time'?
./boost/math/tools/roots.hpp:457:20: error: no member named 'tie' in namespace 'boost::math'; did you mean 'time'?
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/igamma_inverse.hpp:336:17: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/igamma_inverse.hpp:381:27: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/erf_inv.hpp:280:17: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/erf_inv.hpp:285:27: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:91:24: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:94:33: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:142:24: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/airy_ai_bi_zero.hpp:145:33: error: no member named 'make_tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:62:22: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:78:31: error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:78:37: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
./boost/math/special_functions/detail/bessel_jy_zero.hpp:211:24: error: no template named 'tuple' in namespace 'boost::math'
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

I've responded at the [GitHub link](https://github.com/deweylab/RSEM/issues/189):

> It seems that the -std=c++98 flag is not supported by the boost
> version included (1.55.0).
>
> In fact the whole RSEM code base seems to be c++11 ready except for a
> few implicit conversions of `std::istream` to bool. A trivial patch
> like this will allow you to use `-std=c++11` instead:
>
> ```
> be3ea54..0bbf236 100644
> --- a/PairedEndHit.h
> +++ b/PairedEndHit.h @@ -26,7 +26,7 @@ private:    bool PairedEndHit::read(std::istream& in) {    conprb = 0.0;
> -    return (in>>sid>>pos>>insertL);
> +    return !!(in>>sid>>pos>>insertL);  }    void PairedEndHit::write(std::ostream& out) { diff --git a/SingleHit.h
> b/SingleHit.h index b157a15..f3c2d12 100644
> --- a/SingleHit.h
> +++ b/SingleHit.h @@ -43,7 +43,7 @@ protected:    bool SingleHit::read(std::istream& in) {    conprb = 0.0;
> - return (in>>sid>>pos);
> + return bool(in>>sid>>pos);  }    void SingleHit::write(std::ostream& out) { diff --git a/buildReadIndex.cpp b/buildReadIndex.cpp index
> 3837079..4f58022 100644
> --- a/buildReadIndex.cpp
> +++ b/buildReadIndex.cpp @@ -37,15 +37,15 @@ void buildIndex(char* readF, int gap, bool hasQ) {       streampos pos = fin.tellg(); 
>       success = true;
>  
> -     success = (getline(fin, line));
> +        success = !!getline(fin, line);          if (!success) continue;
> -     success = (getline(fin, line));
> +        success = !!getline(fin, line);          if (!success) continue;
>           if (hasQ) {
> -         success = (getline(fin, line));
> +         success = !!getline(fin, line);
>           if (!success) continue;
> -         success = (getline(fin, line));
> +         success = !!getline(fin, line);
>           if (!success) continue;
>           }
> ```
>
> Otherwise you could find out how to make sure set
> `BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_TUPLE` correctly for your platform (in which case
> Boost Tuple would be used). I don't have access to your compiler to
> test.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions and looking into it. For instance, [RSEM tool package can be downloaded from here](https://github.com/deweylab/RSEM/archive/v1.3.3.tar.gz) and [compiled using](https://github.com/deweylab/RSEM#compilation)

I am not familiar with this point `trivial patch like this will allow you to use `-`std=c++11`. Do I need to separately installing with IT Admin or run in the Mac OSX terminal?

Comment: I did obviously compiler RSEM, because I couldn't have provided you the patch otherwise. The patch is a unified diff which describes 6 lines of code (-/+) pairs in 3 files. You can manually apply (or use any version control you want) them and replace `gnu++98` with `c++11` in the Makefile. All these actions can be done with a text editor and from the terminal if you want.

Comment: thank you very much, this is noted. I did replace `gnu++98` with `c++11` in the `Makefile`. Then, execute `make` in the `RSEM` directory. It throws the same errors again. It seems like I have to individually open files using `nano PairedEndHit.h`, `nano SingleHit.h`, and `buildReadIndex.cpp`. Then copy the lines of code that you provided in these files.

Comment: Yeah. As I said, you can automate that with source control (e.g. `git apply`) or even with general command line utilities. But since it seems you are not familiar with these tools, perhaps the simplest is to make the edits manually.